# The {documentation} tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

I'm confused about the [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation) tag. Its tag wiki excerpt states:

> You should tag questions as {documentation} when they address issues related to the writing of documenting TeX packages, or to packages designed for documenting TeX code, e.g., ltxdoc.

So, as I understand this, the tag is about how to *write* documentation (e.g., about dtx files).

On the other hand, most of the questions tagged [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation) are actually about *finding* documentation. Further, [manual](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manual) is a synonym of [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation).

What is the correct use? Should we split the tag into two?

(Compare also [books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books), [tutorials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorials) and [Tags about documentation](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/tags-about-documentation).)

[Sorry for this shameless way to move this question up, but I was just about to ask the same thing, and I cannot offer a bounty on meta (which I would gladly do if I could). **tohecz**]

Comment: Apparently the http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/tags-about-documentation question is also by me — is it bad that I can't remember writing it and what the ultimate decision was?

Comment: Proposal: Let's close this question as a duplicate of your older one because that has some discussion going on and they're basically about the same issue. Let's then finalize the discussion in the other question. It seems like we almost have a kind-of consensus, and only need to change some of the tag wikis, and possibly retag some questions.

Answer (score 5):

This still hasn’t been worked out and I (doncherry) was about to ask the same question as well.

## Status quo

as of 2014-09-20:

> - [books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books): {books} is for questions which deal with books about TeX, LaTeX and other topics of this site. […]
> - [tutorials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorials): Should be used when asking about obtaining tutorials, how-tos, introductory books etc. For questions about writing such material, use the tag {documentation} instead.
> - [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation): {documentation} is about the writing of *TeX package documentation and packages designed for documenting *TeX code, e.g. ltxdoc.
> - [manuals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manuals): synonym of [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation)

## Problems

- None of the opinions at [Tags about documentation](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/tags-about-documentation) is followed regarding [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation), although most of the top questions are not about the writing of documentation, but about existing (or not) pieces of documentation.
- If we’re hypothetically accepting the current wiki meaning of [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation), then:

  - [manuals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manuals) shouldn’t be a synonym of [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation).
  - We don’t have a tag for package documentation – not writing it, but e.g. obtaining it, about some specific piece of documentation …

## Proposal

- Keep the de facto-meaning of [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation) and change its wiki accordingly
- Create a new tag [documentation-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation-writing) and retag the few questions where it’s necessary

I personally would rather have [manuals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manuals) as a synonym of [tutorials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorials), but this didn’t seem to be the consensus at [Tags about documentation](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/tags-about-documentation), so we can keep that the way it is.

Comment: after reading all the referenced items, i think that having a tag [documentation-writing] would be a good thing.  a wiki explanation could say something about this being a "how to" topic.  that would mean changing the wiki for [documentation] as proposed.  +1